# What is the ZODB data model?

Tags: python, zodb

Suppose that I define a new persistent class Account as is described in
in [the ZODB tutorial](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/documentation/tutorial.htm).

```
import persistent, ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage, import transaction

class Account(persistent.Persistent):

    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 0.0

    def deposit(self, amount):
    self.balance += amount

    def cash(self, amount):
        assert amount < self.balance
        self.balance -= amount

storage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage('mydata.fs')
db = ZODB.DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root

root.accounts = BTrees.OOBTree.BTree()
root.accounts['account-1'] = Account()

transaction.commit()
```

After running this script I wrote another script to access the object
that I have created.

```
import persistent, ZODB, ZODB.FileStorage

class Account(persistent.Persistent):
     ...

storage = ZODB.FileStorage.FileStorage('mydata.fs')
db = ZODB.DB(storage)
connection = db.open()
root = connection.root

print(root.accounts['account-1'])
print(root.accounts['account-1'].balance)
```

The output of this second script is:

```
<__main__.Account object at 0x95fbaac>
0.0
```

But if I comment lines where class Account is defined the output is:

```
<persistent broken __main__.Account instance '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(root.accounts['account-1'].balance)
AttributeError: 'Account' object has no attribute 'balance'
```

I guest that object declarations is not attached to the database, so
we can't execute or methods that I previously defined in Account. But
it is not clear to me if I have some access to attributes in objects
where no class definition is found. So my question is: Is there a base
data model that can be used to access objects without class
definitions in ZODB?

My question is also motivated by the following concerns:

I'm habituated to applications where databases have data models that
are separated from application logic. Suppose I incorporate a new
module X (defining classes) in a application and then I discovered that
X is creating problems in my application. In the classic approach, I
always can stop the application and inspect the database without the
logic layer to analyze and try to fix the data. And then, start the
application again without the module X. But in ZODB I don't found
documentation about a data layer that can be used without class
definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ZODB is built on top of the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html); persistence merely serves to detect changes and to create boundaries between records (so changes to one persistent object do not require writing away the whole object tree).

The data model then *is your Python code*; `pickle` merely stores refences to the class locations, like your `Account`, to restore instances from.

When you removed the `Account` class definition, all `persistent` could give you is a placeholder object for the data. It tells you that `pickle` was looking for a class named `Account` in the module `__main__`, and that the ZODB object id is 2.

You can still inspect the attributes your `Account` instance had in the `__Broken_state__` attribute of the 'broken' object, if you wanted to introspect that data.

Comment: I guess that the `__Broken_state__` model is similar to the OEM data model. Thus, with broken class references ZODB has similar capabilities to JSON and other data models compatibles with OEM.